# How to find the first index of type

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get the first index of an item with a provided type.

```
func firstIndexPath<T>(of type: T) -> IndexPath? {
     for (sectionIndex, section) in sections.enumerated() {
        for (rowIndex, row) in section.enumerated() {
            if row.cell is T {
                 return IndexPath(row: rowIndex, section: sectionIndex)
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

and caller usage:

```
let index = firstIndexPath(of: MyCell.self)
```

But, My function always returns false.
Even I have an array of type MyCell.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What about using Identical Operator (==) to compare two cells, since they are both same and points to same reference instead of 'is' ?

Comment: @DebashishDas I don't have the reference to the cell at this moment. that's why I'm using type

Comment: What *is* the type of `row.cell` when you expect the function to return `true`? You can print it at runtime with `print(type(of: row.cell))`

Comment: A type check of the **view** at runtime is *unswifty*. You should get the index (path) with the help of the **model**.

Comment: @MartinR Is of  type  `Optional<UITableViewCell> some : MyApp.MyCell`

Comment: @MartinR Btw, If I'm using the type itself like so: `if row.cell is MyCell {` it works

Comment: Read the comment by vadian, why do you need to find a cell of a particular type? Maybe you should find the corresponding index path based on your data source (model objects) instead?